# which api I use to intergrate Cassandra with spring -rest

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, cassandra-2.0, kundera

I am new Cassandra (not even idea of writing queries) and I want to integrate Cassandra with spring rest application. I go through many links but I am not able to decide which one is better spring-data-Cassandra or Kundera or Easy-Cassandra.

Kindly tell me advantage or disadvantage over each other so that I can select and use them in my application.

Is there a possibility to use the combination of spring-data-Cassandra or Kundera?

Comment: You can't go wrong with using a DataStax supported driver (whichever you choose).  The only disadvantage I see of integrating with something like Spring, is that it abstracts Cassandra from your app, and makes it harder for you to learn/understand it.

Comment: @Rahul have u tried Kundera?

Comment: NO. I found Integration with spring is very simple and full fill my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think when learning Cassandra it is important to know exactly which queries are being executed.

If you want to avoid writing boilerplate I would use the DataStax Java Driver's Mapping API:  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/objectMappingApi.html?scroll=object-mapping-api

Straightforward example on my github: https://github.com/chbatey/cassandra-customer-events/tree/mapping/src/main/java/info/batey/eventstore

Comment: I agree on the use of the Java Mapping API.  I answered this question for someone yesterday, where I briefly explained how to use that API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166695/jdbi-like-layer-for-cassandra/27173426#27173426